# How to check if two GUID match in .NET (C#)?

Tags: c#, .net

How to check if two `GUID` match?

Using the following C# code, how to match if `g2` has same `GUID` as `g1`:

```
Guid g1 = new Guid("{10349469-c6f7-4061-b2ab-9fb4763aeaed}");
Guid g2 = new Guid("{45DF902E-2ECF-457A-BB0A-E04487F71D63}");
```

Comment: `Guid` correctly implements equality, so `Equals` or `==`.

Answer (score 32):

You use either of the `Guid.Equals` overloads.

So in practical terms:

```
Guid g1 = ...
Guid g2 = ...

if (g1.Equals(g2)) { /* guids are equal */ }
```

Note that `System.Guid` implements the equality-operator as well, so the following will also work:

```
if (g1 == g2) { /* guids are equal */ }
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing right direction, I thought `Equals` matches by reference type.

Comment: @AmitKB Take a look at [`public bool Equals(Guid g)`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/a.html#54bcc19a4028b3f2)

Answer (score -14):

`ToString()` method of GUID will result consisten string value, so it can be used to match.

Check [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kJsihp) DotNetFiddle for this test.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Two distinct GUIDs
        Guid g1 = new Guid("{10349469-c6f7-4061-b2ab-9fb4763aeaed}");
        Guid g2 = new Guid("{45DF902E-2ECF-457A-BB0A-E04487F71D63}");       

        // GUID similar to 'g1' but with mixed case
        Guid g1a = new Guid("{10349469-c6f7-4061-b2ab-9fb4763AEAED}");

        // GUID similear to 'g1' but without braces
        Guid g1b = new Guid("10349469-c6f7-4061-b2ab-9fb4763AEAED");

        // Show string value of g1,g2 and g3
        Console.WriteLine("g1 as string: {0}\n", g1.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("g2 as string: {0}\n", g2.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("g1a as string: {0}\n", g1a.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("g1b as string: {0}\n", g1b.ToString());

        // g1 to g1a match result
        bool resultA = (g1.ToString() == g1a.ToString());

        // g1 to g1b match result
        bool resultB = (g1.ToString() == g1b.ToString());

        // Show match result
        Console.WriteLine("g1 matches to g1a: {0}\n", resultA );
        Console.WriteLine("g1 matches to g1b: {0}", resultB );      
    }
}
```

Output

> g1 as string: 10349469-c6f7-4061-b2ab-9fb4763aeaed
>
> g2 as string: 45df902e-2ecf-457a-bb0a-e04487f71d63
>
> g1a as string: 10349469-c6f7-4061-b2ab-9fb4763aeaed
>
> g1b as string: 10349469-c6f7-4061-b2ab-9fb4763aeaed
>
> g1 matches to g1a: True
>
> g1 matches to g1b: True

Comment: There's absolutely no need to convert to string, you're adding unnecessary overhead - it's a terrible idea. Just use `g1 == g2` or `g1.Equals(g2)`